# Help identify fender mounting clamp?

Tags: parts, mechanical, accessories

My bike has metal fenders that attach to the frame through ~3mm steel arms that are clamped and held in place with a piece of plastic that is screwed to the frame (M5 bolts) - as shown on the photo.

[image]

I lost two of those. Does anyone know what can be used as a replacement? What would be a proper English term for this type of a hardware?

Comment: I've no idea what you would call one of those, but if you were to send that photo to the manufacturer of your mudguards they could probably help

Comment: I've never seen those except when shipped with the fenders.  Check your fender manufacturer's web site.

Comment: I'd try making something from a chunk of aluminium block. You'd need two holes, and a thin slot cut into it, and some rounding with a file.  Perhaps make the new ones a bit longer?  and maybe flare the end of the stay so its less likely to slip backward.

Comment: @Criggie, thanks for your comment. I was thinking of fabricating the part, though I was thinking about a piece of plastic (was just not sure how to find a suitable original piece). Aluminum or other metal is an interesting idea. Any thoughts of what can such piece of metal be purchased? I went through my garage hardware but don't find anything I could repurpose.

Comment: @DmitryAlergant what about two penny washers?  small enough middle hole for your frame bolt.  A bit of a bend in the outside washer's lip to retain the stay ?

Comment: @criggie bingo! That should work and seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

They may be called [R-clips](https://velo-orange.com/collections/fender-parts/products/vo-r-clip-4-pack) in the US. The hole of the R encloses the fender stay (the metal rod). The stay is one of the fender's points of contact with the frame/fork and it prevents the fender from flopping around. A hex bolt goes through the legs of the R into an eyelet (i.e. a bolt hole) on each side of the frame or fork. The link goes to a US online only store (Velo Orange). However, your local bike store could probably order similar items from their distributors, and you could also find them on other sites. I do not recommend any specific retailer; I only selected Velo Orange because they have decent pictures and descriptions.

Not all fenders may attach to your frame/fork's fender mounts with R-clips. The pic below, courtesy of [Sheldon Brown's site](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/fenders.html), shows SKS's breakaway stay fitting. The fitting is designed to quickly break away if something (e.g. a stray branch) gets jammed between the fender and the wheel. This should hopefully save your fender.

[image]

Or if you look carefully at the image below from [road.cc](https://road.cc/content/buyers-guide/216720-16-best-mudguards-any-type-bike-keep-dry-when-its-wet-guards-race-bikes), some stays may be designed to bolt directly to an eyelet without an additional piece of hardware. The stays are bent in a little loop, and it seems like you'd put a hex bolt right through that loop. Look where the fender stays connect to the frame near the bottom of the seatstays.

[image]

I am not certain if R-clip is standardized terminology in all parts of the world. In English, some differences exist between US and UK terminology (e.g. US: crankset and Campy, UK: chainset and Campag), and I'm not sure if this term is identical on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Something very similar is also called a P clip (compare the shape when closed). You may find one that fits, possibly with a layer of heat shrink sleeving around the mudguard support rod (mudguard vs fender is a good example of transatlantic terminology differences)

Comment: R-Clip is usually a wire clip -  [R clip](https://recovery-equipment.co.uk/product/baby-r-clip-s9/#&gid=1&pid=1) vs a [P Clip](https://www.nyfast.com/modules/lazyloading/img/grey.gif) -comes in different materials - which is whats needed here

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be easy to find these - it seems I was over optimistic.

When I can't buy something at a reasonable price I start thinking of ways to make the part.

It may not be pretty but you could make a rod clamp like that from a bit of flat aluminum or steel folded around the fender rod and then drill a hole for the bolt.

Something like this
[image]

It would take a bit of experimentation and strategic use of washers to get the right clamping force.

Comment: Similar pieces are available as "cable clamps" in US hardware stores.

Comment: If you need a specific size that you can't buy, it's worth nothing that these aren't it made from aluminium. Most are steel, and even plastic (nylon) is common, but aluminium won't last, it's much too prone to fatigue. Steel of course is harder to work

Comment: That's what I'd call a "P clip".

Comment: Thanks! I like this suggestion. I was obviously thinking of standard cable clamps, but thought nylon cable clamps (ones that can accommodate 5mm bolt) would have too narrow opening, and too weak. Bending a piece of steel may be the right solution. Thanks!